# How do I get the previous revision number of an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, powershell

I am planning to create a Powershell script that detects changes in several svn repositories and then performs some operations on each of those repositories, like copying changed files or copying the entire repository into a build site.

I have a simple function that gets the latest version of a repository:

```
function Get-SvnRevision($dir=".")
{
    ([xml](svn info $dir --xml)).info.entry.revision
}
```

My idea is that once I get the current revision number, compare it with the previous revision number and if they are not the same, then perform some operations as mentioned above.

How I get the previous revision number so that I can compare it to the latest one and then do some operations?

Comment: Have you looked at using a Continuous Integration server like [CCNet](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) instead, to kick off those tasks? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I know of CCNet and I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I am trying for a simpler solution as I don't think we would be allowed to introduce one more "complication" into our process. I wish I could use CCNet, but I can't.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that this is a solved problem. CCNet is not terribly "complex", and IMHO trying to reinvent its functionality will be more of a complication in your process than building upon someone else's already-proven software.

Comment: I mentioned it as "complications", not because I think it is. Thats what the management thinks. I think CCNet is great and I have used it in the past. But I also understand that even if I hit upon this solution it still would be a maintenance problem. I may have to convince my lead to let us use CCNet.

Comment: anytime you're writing a script to look into the status of multiple repos and move stuff around, you're long past complex.

Comment: CCNet is less of a complication than writing a custom script or set of scripts to manage the exact tasks that CCNet is designed to do. If you need to sell it to management (management shouldn't be making technical decisions in the first place...), pitch it this way: you can spend 20 hours putting together a set of scripts to do the job, with all the risk that is involved with new code (bugs, missed requirements, performance, security), or you can spend 12 hours installing & configuring a tool that's already well-tested and proven to do exactly the same task.

Comment: I accepted the answer since I learnt about post-commit hooks and how they can be used, but I decided to go with CCNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to move from another side: using [post-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html)

- It fires automatically after each commit
- It can be any code (Powershell also), which can be executed by server's OS
- Subversion passes to script all needed (for `svnlook` subcommands in script) details (path to repo + revision id) as parameters